# Is it normal that root's nix-env is visible from non-root user?

Tags: nixos

When I install a package as root via `sudo nix-env -i <pkg>`, should the package be visible from non-root users?

Since this is not system-wide installation like `nixos-rebuild`, should the package be visible only for `root`?

Start with empty env for root and non-root

```
[wizzup@ ~] $ nix-env -q
[wizzup@ ~] $ sudo nix-env -q
```

Install [buku](https://github.com/jarun/Buku) via sudo

```
[wizzup@ ~] $ sudo nix-env -i buku
installing ‘buku-2.9’
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/a77imw0grmx4f7659ff07p5j5kxnnjw2-user-environment’
created 2 symlinks in user environment
```

No `buku` in non-root user env

```
[wizzup@ ~] $ nix-env -q
```

There is `buku` in root env

```
[wizzup@ ~] $ sudo nix-env -q
buku-2.9
```

But non-root user able to use it even it is not in his env

```
[wizzup@ ~] $ buku --version
2.9
```

To verify it is `root` env

```
$ sudo -i

[root@earth:~]# nix-env -q
buku-2.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, it is a design choice of NixOS to consider that packages installed by root are packages that the administrator wants all users to have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you could complement with a link to the docs reiterating your answer.